# Sugar CRM, Getting auto increment value in the custom field

Tags: php, mysql, sugarcrm

I am using Sugar Professional 6 and also checking the same in community version.
In project module, I have project Name which should generate automatically from another field called MSO with the prefix and auto increment number.

For ex.

MSO Code- **Xyz**
Project Name should be- **Xyz1**

For next record

MSO Code- **Abcd**
Project Name should be- **Abcd1**

MSO Code- **Xyz**
Project Name should be- **Xyz2**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definately make it using logic hooks on the project module save action.

- Create a logic_hooks.php in custom/modules/*myModule*/

  ```
  <?
  $hook_array = Array(); 
  $hook_array['after_save'] = Array(); 
  $hook_array['after_save'][] = Array(0, 'myName', 'custom/modules/myModule/logic_hooks/file.php','myClass', 'myMethod');   
  ?>
  ```
- Create file.php in /custom/modules/*myModule*/logic_hooks/

  ```
  <?php
  class myClass{
      function myMethod(&$bean, $event, $arguments){
          // Do something with $bean (e.g. load the MSO code and calculate the project name, and afterwards set the project name to the found value.)
      }
  }
  ?>
  ```

For more info see: http://developers.sugarcrm.com/docs/OS/6.1/-docs-Developer_Guides-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.1.0-Chapter%204%20Customizing%20Sugar.html#9000530

Comment: I guess this will generate after save, What I need is user should able to see the generated code in the screen before click on Save. Is it possible, Simply auto number also helpful, but that should display in the form before save.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I used AJAX to achieve same thing

Answer (score 0):

if you want to generate the auto increment field just add simple field name unique id in the studio and go the database and change the value to the auto increment.

Thanks